# Angular 2 storing Basic authentication credentials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have an AngularJS 2 application that requests a file download from a server that requires Basic authentication method to allow the request. Since there is no way of downloading large files using XHR/Angular 2 http module. I'd like to imitate how the browser store the credentials when signing in using the Basic authentication dialog. So I can just download the file using "window.open".